# Getting a dataframe of combinations from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a following list of dictionaries:

```
options = [{'A-1': ['x', 'y']},
           {'A-3': ['x', 'y', 'z']},
```

Values of each dictionary (e.g. `x` and `y`) are basically the options that keys (e.g. `A-1`) can have. How can I have the following dataframe of combinations? Only one value (e.g. either `x` or `y`) of a key (e.g. `A-1`) can can take **1** at a time. All values of a dictionary cannot be **0** at a time.

I have trying to use `itertools.combinations()`, but couldn't find the way to get the desired result.

[image]

This way I can find the number of combinations `n_comb` and number of connections `n_conn` which will be number of rows and columns of the dataframe.

```
n_conn = 0
n_comb = 1
for dic in options:
    for key in dic:
        n_comb = n_comb * len(dic[key])
        n_conn = n_conn + len(dic[key])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `pandas.get_dummies` and `merge`:

```
dfs = [pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(o)).assign(merge=1) for o in options]
new_df = dfs[0].merge(dfs[1], on="merge").drop("merge", 1)
print(new_df)
```

Or make it more flexible using `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

new_df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.merge(y, on="merge"), dfs).drop("merge", 1)
```

Output:

```
   A-1_x  A-1_y  A-3_x  A-3_y  A-3_z
0      1      0      1      0      0
1      1      0      0      1      0
2      1      0      0      0      1
3      0      1      1      0      0
4      0      1      0      1      0
5      0      1      0      0      1
```

Comment: Thank you. But this will not work if the number of dictionaries in a list grow.

Comment: @anarz I've updated more flexible (i.e. suited for any number of `dict`) version as well. Kindly check :)